# Yum is reporting 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum

I have two EC2 instances that are very similar. Exactly one of them is giving me this problem.

Yum works exactly as expected on one server and on the other I get 401 errors no matter what I ask yum to do for me.

Here is 1 example:

```
yum repolist -v | grep baseurl
```

which outputs:

```
https://rhui2-cds01.us-west-2.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 401 - Unauthorized
Trying other mirror.
https://rhui2-cds02.us-west-2.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 401 - Unauthorized
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (Red Hat Update Infrastructure 2.0 Client Configuration Server 7),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

         1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

         2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
                upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
                distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
                packages for the previous distribution release still work).

         3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
                        yum --disablerepo=rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7 ...

         4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
                will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
                again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

                        yum-config-manager --disable rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7
                or
                        subscription-manager repos --disable=rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7

         5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
                Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
                so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
                slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
                compromise:

                        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://rhui2-cds01.us-west-2.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 401 - Unauthorized
https://rhui2-cds02.us-west-2.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 401 - Unauthorized
```

While the same command on a different EC2 instance outputs:

```
Repo-baseurl : https://rhui2-cds01.us-west-2.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/7/x86_64/os/
Repo-baseurl : https://rhui2-cds02.us-west-2.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/
Repo-baseurl : https://rhui2-cds02.us-west-2.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/x86_64/rh-common/os/
```

All of the propsed *solutions* in the first output don't seem relevant, as the repositories are set identically on both machines.

Is it an SELinux config issue? I have disabled it on the machine in question.

My /etc/yum.conf file is identical on both machines:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=3
```

How can I resolve this issue and install new packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little further digging turned up [a post on the AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=128658).

It has to do with the instance somehow losing the *billingProducts* info.  You can verify that with the following command:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | grep billingProducts
```

A working instance should show a product code, but for my problematic instance the value is `null`.

The suggestions on that AWS Forum Post are:

```
To workaround the issue please try one of these two options:

1- From the modified instance ( if you still have it ) create an AMI directly. 

2- If the only source that you have is the snapshot then take these steps:

 - Launch a new instance from a good RHEL AMI, stop and detach the root EBS volume.

 - Stop the broken instance, detach all EBS volumes and attach to the new instance and restart ( remembering to associate the broken instance's EIP if applicable )

 - Alternatively you could snap-shot the broken instance's EBS volumes, and attach volumes created from these snapshots to the new instance.

 - Verify billingProducts value is present by running 
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

For me, the first option (create an AMI directly) did no good and I still had no *billingProducts*, but following the second suggestion did work.

**Now YUM operates properly again.**

Comment: If you have solved this problem, please accept the answer by ticking the check mark so that it turns green.